# .NET Core API not working after deploying on Azure

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple .net core web api with angular app on the client side.

When I call my api locally (http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register) it works without any problems. After deploying app to azure and calling it (https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/auth/register), I get a 400 Bad Request error without any message.

I was trying to configure app service and sql server on azure portal but I'm not sure what to change.

AuthController.cs

```
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserToRegisterDto userToRegister)
        {
            if (await AuthService.UserExists(userToRegister.UserName))
            {
                return BadRequest("Username already exists");
            }

            var userToCreate = new User() { UserName = userToRegister.UserName };

            await AuthService.Register(userToCreate, userToRegister.Password);

            // TODO: Change to return CreatedAtRoute
            return StatusCode(201);
        }
```

AuthService.cs

```
        public async Task<User> Register(User user, string password)
        {
            GenerateHashedPassword(user, password);

            await usersRepository.Create(user);

            return user;
        }
```

auth.service.ts

```
  private baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'auth/';

  public register(userToRegister: UserToRegister) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'register', userToRegister);
  }
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/api/'
};
```

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'api/'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your log in your azure web app there would be log when you accessing your web app

Second check exception capture in your azure web app any exeception occur will be capture with status code and the detail

Finally try to change your api url like this. But I dont think the error come from this setting

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/'
};
```

Update to auto run migrate when you deploy new version in azure web app you can add these code snippet

```
public class Startup
{
    ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(...);

        ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        UpdateDatabase(app);

        ...
    }

    private static void UpdateDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices
            .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
            .CreateScope())
        {
            using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>())
            {
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've checked the failed request log on azure and it says System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Users'. I've tried (unsccessfully) to change connection string to the one given on azure SQL database in appsettings.json. Then I tried adding it to web.config file that was generated when using dotnet publish command but it didn't solve this problem either.

Comment: No, shouldn't migation be runned automatically when launching application for the first time?

Comment: Locally I use update-database command, during deployment options Databases and EntityFrameworkMigrations were disabled at first, but after deleting and adding again connection string in appsettings.json option "Use this connection string at runtime" is enabled but something is wrong with migrations [error screenshot](https://ibb.co/zGnQb8L)

Comment: in Startup.cs I added:
```            
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly("TutorApp.Infrastructure")));`
``
and then in PMC: add-migration mymigrationname and then update-database

Comment: Ok, I've run migration again on azure database, I fixed my login in one place in connection string because it was invalid and now it works. One thing is that I'm not sure if it's possible to run migrations automatically after deployment, now I have to run migrations manually everytime

Comment: The code I show you will let you run migration automatically when you access your web app

Comment: Please try giving an answer to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77600235/4512005)**. Thanks!