# How do I make this Angular 16 app communicate with a .NET API on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, azure

I am working on a app consisting of a .NET API and an Angular 16 front-end. It is deployed on a free Microsoft Azure account.

In `src\environments\environment.prod.ts` I have:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'https://localhost:7231',
  baseUrl: 'https://localhost:44427'
};
```

There is a proxy configuration file that discerns between the ports above:

```
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:56482';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/auth",
      "/Segment",
      "/_configuration",
      "/.well-known",
      "/Identity",
      "/connect",
      "/ApplyDatabaseMigrations",
      "/_framework",
   ],
    proxyTimeout: 10000,
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

The app works fine on the local development environment.

I have deployed the API via Visual Stidio's **Publish** option and the Angular client from VS Code, with the help of the **Azure App Service** extension.

#### The problem

A problem arises when the app is deployed to Azure.

The API URL is `https://my-app-api.azurewebsites.net`, while the client stays at `https://my-app-client.azurewebsites.net`.

The problem is that the client and the API do not communicate.

The URL `https://my-app-api.azurewebsites.net` throws an `HTTP ERROR 500` error.

I have added the above URLs in `src\environments\environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'https://my-app-api.azurewebsites.net',
  baseUrl: 'https://my-app-client.azurewebsites.net'
};
```

It did **not** fix the problem.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you change `target` to the azure URL? What is the error? 404?

Comment: @MateusZampol  The API throws a 500 error. How do I change the target?

Comment: @MateusZampol From the front-end, the remote (IP) address 20.104.224.19:443 responds with 404. It can not find `_configuration/MyApp`

Answer (score 0):

The [`src/environments/environment.prod.ts`](https://angular.io/guide/build) is used for defining environment-specific variables for the production build of the application. It typically includes the base URL for the API.

... But, simply defining the API URL is *not* enough to establish communication. The Angular app needs a service to handle HTTP requests using this URL (typically using [`HttpClient`: `npm install @angular/common/http`](https://angular.io/api/common/http)) to make requests to the API.
That service utilizes the API URL from the `environment.prod.ts` file, yes, but the *implementation* of the service itself is done elsewhere in the code.

And if the Angular app and the .NET API are hosted on different domains (which is often the case), [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/angular-cors-guide-examples-and-how-to-enable-it/) needs to be enabled and properly configured on the server-side (.NET API). That is not something that can be handled by Angular's environment configuration file.

```bash
┌──────────────────────┐  HTTP     ┌──────────────────────┐  HTTP    ┌─────────────────────┐
│ Angular 16 Front-End │ ────────> │ .NET API (Azure App) │ <─────── │ Azure SQL Database  │
└──────────────────────┘ Request   └──────────────────────┘ Response └─────────────────────┘
```

In your Angular app, create a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4) that will handle HTTP requests to your .NET API. The convention is to place such services in a directory named `services` (or similar), often under the `app` directory.
For instance, if you are creating a service named `ApiService` to handle HTTP requests to your .NET API, the file could be named `api.service.ts` and placed in the `src/app/services/` directory. The full path would be `src/app/services/api.service.ts`.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/your-endpoint');
  }

  // Additional methods to interact with the API
}
```

To allow communication between your Angular app and the .NET API, you need to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in your .NET API, [typically found in the `Startup.cs` file](https://code-maze.com/enabling-cors-in-asp-net-core/#enablecors) in a .NET Core or .NET 5/6 application.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
      builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://your-angular-app.com")
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader());
  });

  // Other service configurations
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

  // Other middleware
}
```

Comment: That is a great effort and I really appreciated it. But the application _does_ work locally. I want to move it online (deploy on Azure) with minimal changes. How can I so that?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I believe those are the minimal changes which would make your application work in a remote Azure environment.

Comment: In fact, the important part for the local setup is `const target = ...` - wich discriminates front-end from back-end via proxy. It is a Visual Studio template for the entire application...

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Yes: in many Visual Studio templates for full-stack applications, there is often a built-in configuration for a development proxy, a configuration where both the frontend (Angular) and the backend (.NET) can be run together in an integrated development environment. That is facilitated by a development server (like IIS Express in the case of .NET applications) that serves both frontend and backend from the same origin.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir With this configuration, when you run the application locally, Angular's development server automatically forwards requests to the .NET backend without needing CORS configuration, as both are served from the same origin by the development server.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir But: When moving to a production environment, especially when deploying to Azure, this integrated setup changes. The Angular frontend and .NET backend are typically deployed as separate services, potentially on different origins. That separation is where CORS and dedicated Angular services for HTTP requests (using `HttpClient`) become important.

Comment: True, but how can the _integrated setup_ be changed? Could it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256188/discussion-between-vonc-and-razvan-zamfir).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already mentioned that you are receiving a 500 Internal Server Error. It seems that the issue is on the backend side of things.

I would suggest you to point your .net backend locally into the hosted DB in Azure via the configuration and re-try the request which is getting 500 Internal server errors on the hosted environment with a simple postman request similar to the hosted environment API call.

Doing so you will be able to find out what is going wrong in that particular request.

Comment: The local app is made from a (more or less) monolithic .NET & Angular template provided by Visual Studio. I would love to know how to deploy it as such, instead of separate components. Does Azure offer this possibility?